# Problemas com session_start()

Tags: php, apache, session

Estou com problema no meu código PHP para o  **Login de Usuário**.
Este código está funcionando em máquina local, porém eu subi na minha instância amazon e no momento em que faço o login de usuário o servidor não autentica a sessão.
A página **login.php** está em um subdomínio login.xxxx.com.br e a página restrita está em outro subdomínio paginarestrita.xxxx.com.br, portanto quando eu vou debugar o código e chamo as variáveis da página de login na área restrita o apache informa que a variável não foi definida ou seja o apache no meu servidor não consegue abrir uma sessão de **domínios www** diferentes, pois realizei testes com os arquivos em mesmo subdomínio.

**login:**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
require('db_conn.php');
if(isset($_POST['entrar'])){
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $senha = $_REQUEST['senha'];
    $sql= ("SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario ='$usuario' AND senha ='$senha'");
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    $results= mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($results == 0){
        echo "<script>alert('Erro ao logar')</script>";
        echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='5;URL=http://portal.xxxxx.com.br'>";
    }else{
        // Cria uma sessão que identifica se o usuário efetuou o login
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["usuario"]=$usuario;
        echo "<script>alert('Usuário autenticado com sucesso')</script>";
        echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='0;URL= http://user.xxxxxx.com.br'>";
    }
}
?>
```

**página restrita:**

```
<?php
$usuario=$_SESSION["usuario"];
if(isset($usuario)){
  echo "<script>alert('Usuário autenticado com sucesso')</script>";
  return true;
}else{
    //session_destroy();
    header( "Location:http://portal.xxxxx.com.br/" , TRUE , 302 );
}

// Logout
if( isset($_GET["acao"]) && $_GET["acao"]=="logout" ) {
    // DestrÃ³i todos os dados da sessÃ£o
    session_destroy();
    // Redireciona o usuÃ¡rio para o formulÃ¡rio de login
    header( "Location:http://portal.xxxxxx.com.br/" , TRUE , 302 );
    exit;   
}
?>
```

Comment: No teu `login.php` o segundo `session_start();` está a mais e deve ser retirado. Na tua página restrita, falta-te o `session_start();` no inicio do ficheiro para que possas usar a variável de sessão `$_SESSION["usuario"]`.

Comment: Ivan, reverti sua última edição, pois ela parecia ser baseada na resposta do Guilherme. Isso acabou mudando a pergunta, e invalidando pelo menos uma das respostas já existentes. Para esclarecer dúvidas sobre cada resposta, use os comentários abaixo delas, ou o bate-papo. Mas nenhuma das respostas atuais resolve o seu problema?

Comment: @bfavaretto Nenhuma das respostas resolveu o meu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Isso ocorre por conta do cookie que salva o sessão, geralmente com nome de PHPSESSION, está restrito à somente um subdomínio.

Verifique, num velho F12 se nos headers de envio na página restrita está incluindo os cookies, com os valores que são informados no headers do login.

Para solucionar, já que o cookie deve está restrito à um subdominio, você tem duas opções:

**1. Alterar o .HTACCESS:**

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .xxxxxx.com.br
```

**2. Alterar o PHP.INI:**

```
session.cookie_domain = ".xxxxxx.com.br"
```

Dessa forma, o cookie será salvo em todo o domínio, e não restrito à um subdomínio. :D

*// Edit:*

Outras solução:

**1. Mudar parametros do 'session_set_cookie':**

```
$configAtual = session_get_cookie_params();

    session_set_cookie_params(
        $configAtual["lifetime"],
        $configAtual["path"],
        '.xxxxxx.com.br',
        $configAtual["secure"],
        $configAtual["httponly"]
    );

    session_start();
```

**2. Ambos devem ter o mesmo session.save_path:**

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/var/lib/php/session'); // exemplo
```

*// Observação:*

Tente utilizar navegador anonimo ou exclua o cookie da sessão antiga e escolha uma mesma pasta para salvar a sessão.

Comment: Ótima resposta, parece ser isto mesmo +1

Comment: @inkeliz que argumento eu utilizo em session.cookie_domain? Eu coloquei ""  no  PHP.INI e não funcionou. Estou debugando com <pre> print_r($_SESSION); </pre> E continua limpo não recebi nenhum dado.

Comment: @IvanFloripa quando você modifica o PHP.INI você deve reiniciar o servidor (no caso do Apache).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é claro que o servidor Web (Apache) foi reiniciado.

Comment: @IvanFloripa Não necessita de *grosseria*, a tal situação não foi óbvia como você imagina e eu estava apenas tentando lhe ajudar.

Comment: Tente com:
"ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.xxxxxx.com.br' );", deve haver um ponto antes do domínio e em seguida o domínio do site. Além disso, faça o que o Renato Tavares disse acima. Baixe o aplicativo no Chrome: EditThisCookie, assim poderá saber se o cookie da sessão está ou não em todas as páginas.

Comment: @Inkeliz Utilizei o EditThisCookie e o código abre o cookie de sessão, também iniciei com <?php session_start(); o código da página restrita porém não aparece sessão aberta na página.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu setei para salvar em uma pasta a sessão.Muito estranho

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento opa ajudaria bastante :)

Comment: //Condição para requisição da criação da sessão

      $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;

      $url = 'http://user.xxxxxx.com.br/createsession.php';
      $data = array('username' => $_POST['usuario']);
      $postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');

      $ch = curl_init(); 
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data)); 
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString); 
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
      $post = curl_exec ($ch);  A formatação aqui é horrível.

Comment: Mas os dados do cookie do session seria retornado ao Curl e não ao navegador do cliente. A sessão seria criada, mas, não iria retornar.

Deveria ser feito então pegar o 'Set-Cookie' do 'response headers' e então criar um 'setcookie' para o cliente. Mas, acho que tem outra solução, melhor, irei editar.

Comment: @Inkeliz Não o código que ele postou se refere a sugestão feita por mim na minha resposta a questão, o código funciona, o problema dele é com outro arquivo atualmente.

Answer (score 1):

1º Tente usar o `session_start();` apenas uma vez no login.

2º Coloque `session_start();` no inicio do arquivo da página restrita.

Acho que a segunda opção é a que vai solucionar o seu problema, lembre-se que você precisa iniciar a sessão antes de tentar verificar se existe valores nela.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar sessão com múltiplos domínios é necessário compartilhar a sessão e o cookie, o arquivo de sessão fica em uma pasta chama `tmp` e cada domínio geralmente possui a sua própria pasta ou "identificação" que não permite as sessões se misturarem, em outras palavras um domínio não pode acessar a sessão de outro (seria uma falha de segurança).

Existem vários métodos para compartilhar uma sessão com vários dominios, uma ideia simples seria criar um domínio isolado que compartilharia os dados usado `<script>`, ficaria algo como:

`<script src="//shared.xxxxxx.com.br/session.php"></script>`

O session.php é quem iria compartilhar os dados, porém isto pode ser um pouco complexo de fazer se você tiver pouco conhecimento sobre trabalho `front-end` combinado com `back-end`

Outra maneira seria usar o próprio PHP para acessar o futuro dominio (no seu caso algo como `user.xxxxxx.com.br`)

Antes de direcionar o acesso, você deve enviar uma requisição para o `user.xxxxxx.com.br`, ficaria algo como (de preferência use poste para minimizar as tentativas de invasão):

Crie um arquivo chamado `createsession.php` no dominio `user.xxxx.com.br` e adicione o seguinte conteudo:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["usuario"] = $_POST['username'];
    echo 'OK';
}
```

No arquivo login você deverá criar uma requisição para o `user.xxxxx.com.br`, adicione isto:

```
$url = 'http://user.xxxxx.com.br/createsession.php';
$data = array('username' => $_POST['usuario']);
$postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data)); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$post = curl_exec ($ch);
```

O resultado do arquivo deve ser algo como:

```
<?php
session_start();

require('db_conn.php');
if(isset($_POST['entrar'])){
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $senha = $_REQUEST['senha'];
    $sql= ("SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario ='$usuario' AND senha ='$senha'");
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    $results= mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($results == 0){
        echo "<script>alert('Erro ao logar')</script>";
        echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='5;URL=http://portal.xxxxx.com.br'>";
    }else{
        // Cria uma sessão que identifica se o usuário efetuou o login
        //session_start(); -- linha desnecessária
        $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;

        $url = 'http://user.xxxxx.com.br/createsession.php';
        $data = array('username' => $_POST['usuario']);
        $postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data)); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        $post = curl_exec ($ch);

        if (trim($post) === 'OK') {
            echo "<script>alert('Usuário autenticado com sucesso')</script>";
            echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='0;URL= http://user.xxxxxx.com.br'>";
        } else {
            $_SESSION["usuario"] = NULL;//Remove sessão

            echo "<script>alert('Não pode compartilhar a sessão')</script>";
            echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='5;URL=http://portal.xxxxx.com.br'>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Este segundo método não é totalmente seguro, porém você pode criar um TOKEN para prevenir tentativas de "HACKEAMENTO" as contas dos usuários.

Comment: Guilherme Não consegui compilar a sessão deu um erro de compilação de variável não definida $post na paginarestrita.php

Comment: Undefined variable: post in /var/www/conaprom/user/index.php on line 8

Comment: Eu não tenho o conhecimento do conteúdo deste arquivo, aparentemente não é uma falha no meu código e sim em outra coisa totalmente isolada. Poderia posta o código inteiro dele?

Comment: Eu vou postar numa nova resposta Guilherme!

Comment: na resposta da minha pergunta, a resposta por comentário o espaço é reduzido.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19704/discussion-between-ivanfloripa-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: @IvanFloripa eu gosto do StackOverflow justamente para evitar discussões, o StackOverflow é um sistema de pergunta e respostas (AKA Q&A) é diferente dos sistemas de fórum, portanto por favor edite a sua questão e adicione o código solicitado no meu comentário anterior. Estou aguardando.

Comment: Por este código ser muito extenso para responder nesta área eu postei em outra área a minha implementação do seu código. @guilherme-nascimento

Comment: @IvanFloripa Poste então o conteúdo do arquivo `/var/www/conaprom/user/index.php` até a linha 15